# Number of sliding window in the string

Tags: permutations

I have to calculate number of sliding window in a string.

If the sample string  is "CHECKIT" and window size is 2
then

1. CH
2. HE
3. EC
4. CK
5. KI
6. IT

Window size may vary for the string.

Comment: if you examine the first letters of your list, you will find something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a word with $n$ alphabets, for eg. `ALPHABETS` has 9 alphabets. Of this, window size is $k$. Total possible ways will be:

$$P = n - k + 1 = 9 - k + 1 = 10 - k$$

---

### $ k = 2 $

1. AL
2. LP
3. PH
4. HA
5. AB
6. BE
7. ET
8. TS

### $k = 4$

1. ALPH
2. LPHA
3. PHAB
4. HABE
5. ABET
6. BETS

and so on...